# boot errors after install failure 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation

Trying to install single boot 14.04 on an Acer Aspire S7 from live USB; the install crashed and now I'm not able to boot.

I've disabled UEFI (to "legacy"), but still not able to install from the live USB. I get the ??? error window one or a few steps in, and then back to the first dialog.

I ran boot-repair and received the following:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/9483049/

But still not able to boot. I'd be happy with no UEFI, no RAID, no Windows, but not sure where to start

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the right release of Ubuntu. I don't know if the Acer is a 32 or 64 bit computer, but most of the newer Intel processors are 64 bit now, so make sure you downloaded the Ubuntu "amd64" version of 14.04. On the Ubuntu site, you can search for the hardware support matrix to see what version of Ubuntu is supported by that Acer model.

Secondly, how did you make the live USB? You might want to download "unetbootin", a good tool that will create a complete bootable USB drive. I found that fully erasing the drive first helps.

Third, when you power on the computer, go into the BIOS and make sure the boot order has the USB drive listed before the disk drive. If the disk drive is first, and you have a corrupted installation, the system will not boot up normally.